# Greedy solution for a variant of complete Knapsack problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming

I'm dealing with a variant of the Knapsack problem:

Given $n$ distinct types of items, each with a value $v_i$ and weight $w_i$ (**both being positive integers**), we **can select an infinite number of each item**. The goal is to pack a knapsack with a maximum weight of $W > 0$ such that the total value of the items is maximized.

The mathematical formulation is:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{n_i}{\text{maximize}} & & \sum_{i=1}^n n_i v_i \\
& \text{subject to} & & \sum_{i=1}^n n_i w_i \le W, \\
&&& n_i \in \mathbb{N}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I recognize that this is the unbounded Knapsack problem, typically addressed using dynamic programming. Nevertheless, I've recently been posed this question in an interview, where the interviewer mentioned the existence of a greedy algorithm solution. Is there truly a greedy approach to solve this problem?

The intuitive approach might be to greedily select the item with the highest value-to-weight ratio, $v_i / w_i$. However, there exists a counterexample: consider $W=10$, with item 1 characterized by $v_1=7, w_1=7$ and item 2 by $v_2=4, w_2=5$. Opting for two of item 2 proves more beneficial than a single instance of item 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sort $v_i/w_i$ in non increasing order and take the items according to that sorting until you can't take any more item.

Comment: There is counterexample, $W=10$, $(v_1, w_1) = (7, 7)$, $(v_2, w_2)=(4, 5)$. I can choose 2 item2 rather than choose 1 item1.

Comment: It is not an exact algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Greedy is optimal for the linear programming relaxation of the bounded knapsack problem, so maybe that's what the interviewer had in mind:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem

Otherwise, greedy is only a heuristic:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Greedy_approximation_algorithm